# C# Loose coupling to access to a property value

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I want to create loosely coupled classes (`PlayerProfile` and `PlayersManager`) and be able to access the value of the `PlayerScore` property (that's implemented in `PlayerProfile`) from `PlayersManager`(without knowing about `PlayerProfile`)

```
public class PlayerProfile : IPlayer
{
    int myScore = 520;

    public int PlayerScore
    {
        get
        {
            return myScore;
        }
    }
}



public interface IPlayer
{
    int PlayerScore { get; }
}



public class PlayersManager
{
    //There is any way to access here to the value of "PlayerScore" without creating an instance
    //of PlayerProfile and without depending in any way of the PlayerProfile (like IClass myClass = new PlayerProfile())?
}
```

*PS: I don't know if using interfaces is the right way to do it or if there is another way.*

Any idea how I can achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: You can pass an `IClass` instance (which might be a ClassA instance or not) to ClassB's methods (for instance its constructor)

Comment: @vc74 Could you detail a bit more how I can do it?

Comment: This question is very unclear. You need to explain the relationship between `ClassB` and `ClassA`/`IClass`. As it stands I don't know what your asking

Comment: @Wadjey ClassB would have the constructor `public ClassB(IClass classObject) { }` and you can then access the `PlayerScore ` from the `classObject` param

Comment: You do understand that `IClass myClass = new ClassA()` is perfectly valid?

Comment: @Wadjey I've added an answer to detail my comment

Comment: @Liam OK I've edit the names of the classes to be more clear

Comment: That doesn't really help.

Comment: After his edit, it looks like he may want to add many `IPlayer` objects to the `PlayersManager`, so a public method that takes an `IPlayer` object instead perhaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detail my comment:

```
public interface IClass
{
     int PlayerScore { get; }
}

public class ClassA : IClass
{
    public int PlayerScore { get; } = 250;
}

public class ClassB
{
    public ClassB(IClass aClass)
    {
        _aClass = aClass;
        // Now you can use _aClass.PlayerScore in the other methods
    }
    private readonly IClass _aClass;
}
```

Now after reading your updated code:

```
public interface IPlayerProfile
{
     int PlayerScore { get; }
}

public class Player : IPlayerProfile
{
    public int PlayerScore { get; } = 250;
}

public class PlayersManager
{
    public Add(IPlayerProfile profile)
    {
        // Use profile.PlayerScore
    }
}
```

Comment: For the OPs FYI this is a dependency injection pattern.

Comment: @vc74 Thanks for your help 

Answer (score 0):

You can use constructor injection. This is a [Dependency Injection Design Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh323705(v=vs.100).aspx). See also: [Dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

```
public class PlayersManager
{
    private readonly IPlayer _player;

    PlayersManager(IPlayer player)
    {
        _player = player;
    }

    public void Manage() // Example
    {
        int score = _player.PlayerScore;
        ...
    }
}
```

---

[Dependency injection frameworks](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Category/IoC) can create and inject the dependency automatically. They work like this (of course the details vary among the different dependency injection frameworks):

Create a dependency injection container in a static class

```
public static class DI
{
    public static SomeContainer Container { get; } = new SomeContainer();
}
```

At program startup register your services

```
DI.Container.Register<IPlayer, PlayerProfile>();
DI.Container.Register<PlayersManager>();
```

Then create a `PlayersManager` with:

```
// This automatically creates a `PlayerProfile` object and a `PlayersManager` object by
// injecting the player profile into the constructor of the manager.
var pm = DI.Container.Resolve<PlayersManager>();
```

It does the same as

```
IPlayer temp = new PlayerProfile();
var pm = new PlayersManager(temp);
```